# huge gap between two forms in bulma

Tags: css, bulma

I have a Bulma CSS form and i want to eliminate the gap between two forms.
Is there a way that this Bulma css can be modified possibly without adding custom css.

```
<section class="section">
  <div class="container">
    <form class="control">
      <div class="columns is-multiline">
        <div class="column is-2">
          <div class="box">
            <h1 class="subtitle">Form Part 1</h1>
            <div class="field">
              <label class="label">col1</label>
              <div class="control has-icons-right">
                <input class="input" type="text" placeholder="col1">
                <i class="fas fa-dollar-sign"></i>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="field">
              <label class="label">col2</label>
              <div class="control has-icons-right">
                <input class="input" type="text" placeholder="col2 ">
                <i class="fas fa-percentage"></i>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="field">
              <label class="label">col3</label>
              <div class="control">
                <div class="select is-fullwidth">
                  <select>
                    <option>drop1</option>
                    <option>drop2</option>
                  </select>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="field">
              <label class="label">col3</label>
              <div class="control">
                <div class="select is-fullwidth">
                  <select>
                    <option>a</option>
                    <option>b</option>
                    <option>c</option>
                  </select>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <a class="button is-primary">Next</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="column is-10">
          <div class="box">
            <h1 class="subtitle">form2</h1>
            <div class="columns ">
              <div class="column is-2">
                <div class="field">
                  <label class="label">col1</label>
                  <div class="control">
                    <input class="input" type="text" placeholder="col1">
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="column is-2">
                <div class="field">
                  <label class="label">col2</label>
                  <div class="control has-icons-right">
                    <input class="input" type="text" placeholder="col2">
                    <i class="fas fa-dollar-sign"></i>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="column is-2">
                <div class="field">
                  <label class="label">col3</label>
                  <div class="control has-icons-right">
                    <input class="input" type="text" placeholder="col3">
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="column is-2">
                <div class="field">
                  <label class="label">col4</label>
                  <div class="control has-icons-right">
                    <input class="input" type="text" placeholder="col4">
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="column is-2">
                <div class="field">
                  <label class="label">col5</label>
                  <div class="control has-icons-right">
                    <input class="input" type="text" placeholder="col5">
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <a class="button is-primary">Next</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="column is-10 is-offset-2">
          <div class="box">
            <h1 class="subtitle">form3</h1>
            <div class="columns">
              <div class="column is-3">
                <div class="field">
                  <label class="label">col1</label>
                  <div class="control">
                    <input class="input" type="text" placeholder="col1">
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="column is-1">
                <div class="field">
                  <label class="label">col2 </label>
                  <div class="control">
                    <input class="input" type="text" placeholder="col2">
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="column is-2">
                <div class="field">
                  <label class="label">col3 </label>
                  <div class="control">
                    <input class="input" type="text" placeholder="col3">
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <a class="button is-primary">Next</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</section>
```

When you post this code on https://codepen.io/JMSmith/pen/yZKxOp

you will notice there is huge gap between Form2 and Form3.

My question is how do i eliminate this gap ?

I am new to Bulma and a novice at css still.

Comment: fyi your codepen doesn't match this code

Comment: Hi Dan thanks for pointing it out I have modified the code pen link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]Take a look at my pen. 2 changes: The main issue was to wrap the second and third forms all in one column, so the left side is its own column, and then the right side contains the other two forms.

Then you need to remove the `offset-2` class from in the `col-is-10` above form3, since this whole right column is only 10 wide.

https://codepen.io/DanOswalt/pen/qgoMNv?editors=1000

```
<section class="section">
  <div class="container">
    <form class="control">
      <div class="columns is-multiline">
        <div class="column is-2">
          <div class="box">
            <h1 class="subtitle">Form Part 1</h1>
            <div class="field">
              <label class="label">col1</label>
              <div class="control has-icons-right">
                <input class="input" type="text" placeholder="col1">
                <i class="fas fa-dollar-sign"></i>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="field">
              <label class="label">col2</label>
              <div class="control has-icons-right">
                <input class="input" type="text" placeholder="col2 ">
                <i class="fas fa-percentage"></i>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="field">
              <label class="label">col3</label>
              <div class="control">
                <div class="select is-fullwidth">
                  <select>
                    <option>drop1</option>
                    <option>drop2</option>
                  </select>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="field">
              <label class="label">col3</label>
              <div class="control">
                <div class="select is-fullwidth">
                  <select>
                    <option>a</option>
                    <option>b</option>
                    <option>c</option>
                  </select>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <a class="button is-primary">Next</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="column is-10">
          <div class="box">
            <h1 class="subtitle">form2</h1>
            <div class="columns ">
              <div class="column is-2">
                <div class="field">
                  <label class="label">col1</label>
                  <div class="control">
                    <input class="input" type="text" placeholder="col1">
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="column is-2">
                <div class="field">
                  <label class="label">col2</label>
                  <div class="control has-icons-right">
                    <input class="input" type="text" placeholder="col2">
                    <i class="fas fa-dollar-sign"></i>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="column is-2">
                <div class="field">
                  <label class="label">col3</label>
                  <div class="control has-icons-right">
                    <input class="input" type="text" placeholder="col3">
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="column is-2">
                <div class="field">
                  <label class="label">col4</label>
                  <div class="control has-icons-right">
                    <input class="input" type="text" placeholder="col4">
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="column is-2">
                <div class="field">
                  <label class="label">col5</label>
                  <div class="control has-icons-right">
                    <input class="input" type="text" placeholder="col5">
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <a class="button is-primary">Next</a>
          </div>


          <div class="column is-10">
            <div class="box">
              <h1 class="subtitle">form3</h1>
              <div class="columns">
                <div class="column is-3">
                  <div class="field">
                    <label class="label">col1</label>
                    <div class="control">
                      <input class="input" type="text" placeholder="col1">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="column is-1">
                  <div class="field">
                    <label class="label">col2 </label>
                    <div class="control">
                      <input class="input" type="text" placeholder="col2">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="column is-2">
                  <div class="field">
                    <label class="label">col3 </label>
                    <div class="control">
                      <input class="input" type="text" placeholder="col3">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <a class="button is-primary">Next</a>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
      </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Form1 is vertical but form2 also has become vertical .I wanted the form2 and form3 to be horizontal with no huge gap between form2 and form3

Comment: hm, i'm not sure why that's happening, I added a screenshot of my codepen in case it's looking different on your screen somehow. This picture shows what you're looking for, right?

Comment: Yes Dan you are correct your screen shot is correct :).

Answer (score 0):

you can delete the  in line 96 
then delete is-offset-2 in line 97 which will be the below code i helped to modify.

Hope it helps you.

```
  <section class="section">
      <div class="container">
        <form class="control">
          <div class="columns is-multiline">
            <div class="column is-2">
              <div class="box">
            <h1 class="subtitle">Form Part 1</h1>
            <div class="field">
              <label class="label">col1</label>
              <div class="control has-icons-right">
                <input class="input" type="text" placeholder="col1">
                <i class="fas fa-dollar-sign"></i>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="field">
              <label class="label">col2</label>
              <div class="control has-icons-right">
                <input class="input" type="text" placeholder="col2 ">
                <i class="fas fa-percentage"></i>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="field">
              <label class="label">col3</label>
              <div class="control">
                <div class="select is-fullwidth">
                  <select>
                    <option>drop1</option>
                    <option>drop2</option>
                  </select>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="field">
              <label class="label">col3</label>
              <div class="control">
                <div class="select is-fullwidth">
                  <select>
                    <option>a</option>
                    <option>b</option>
                    <option>c</option>
                  </select>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <a class="button is-primary">Next</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="column is-10">
          <div class="box">
            <h1 class="subtitle">form2</h1>
            <div class="columns ">
              <div class="column is-2">
                <div class="field">
                  <label class="label">col1</label>
                  <div class="control">
                    <input class="input" type="text" placeholder="col1">
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="column is-2">
                <div class="field">
                  <label class="label">col2</label>
                  <div class="control has-icons-right">
                    <input class="input" type="text" placeholder="col2">
                    <i class="fas fa-dollar-sign"></i>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="column is-2">
                <div class="field">
                  <label class="label">col3</label>
                  <div class="control has-icons-right">
                    <input class="input" type="text" placeholder="col3">
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="column is-2">
                <div class="field">
                  <label class="label">col4</label>
                  <div class="control has-icons-right">
                    <input class="input" type="text" placeholder="col4">
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="column is-2">
                <div class="field">
                  <label class="label">col5</label>
                  <div class="control has-icons-right">
                    <input class="input" type="text" placeholder="col5">
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <a class="button is-primary">Next</a>
          </div>

        <div class="column is-10 is-offset-2">
          <div class="box">
            <h1 class="subtitle">form3</h1>
            <div class="columns">
              <div class="column is-3">
                <div class="field">
                  <label class="label">col1</label>
                  <div class="control">
                    <input class="input" type="text" placeholder="col1">
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="column is-1">
                <div class="field">
                  <label class="label">col2 </label>
                  <div class="control">
                    <input class="input" type="text" placeholder="col2">
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="column is-2">
                <div class="field">
                  <label class="label">col3 </label>
                  <div class="control">
                    <input class="input" type="text" placeholder="col3">
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <a class="button is-primary">Next</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </section>
```